# Solr: how to search documents with the latest version

Tags: solr

I have started using partial updates in Solr 4.5.1 and I found that there are multiple versions of the same doc (to be precise same ID). Is there a way to keep only the latest version or to force the search only to be done for the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Make that ID unique in your schema and you will always have the latest version of that document in your result set. Since any update on that document will overwrite the previous version.

Comment: That's not really true. I found that it depends on overwrite attribute of add command. By default the value of overwrite attribute is true. But it turned out that I was setting it as false and ended up keeping multiple versions over time.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of it. But by detault it is always true so it keeps only a single latest version of that document.

Comment: I have the same problem and in my case it's not an option to overwrite because I need to keep the history. Is there any other way to filter only the latest documents?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, overwrite attribute of add determines whether Solr will keep multiple versions or not. By default overwrite is set to true. But in my case I was setting it to false.